# Orientation Change and Resource Access

Tags: android

On an orientation change, I'm getting this error:

E/AndroidRuntime(  333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.goodsexnetwork.StressRelief/com.goodsexnetwork.StressRelief.StressReliefActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class

I've determined that it's caused by an ImageView trying to load a resource:

android:src="@drawable/lotus_flower"

I don't understand what the problem is. The app normally has no difficulty loading the resource. If the activity is being recreated, shouldn't the XML work the same as before?

Comment: Device orientation causes no difference in how resources are loaded. I suspect something is wrong with your layout, can you post the layout file you are using?

Comment: Please show us more code, it's hard to understand the problem only by seeing the exception.

Comment: Somehow, I managed to resolve the issue. I'm not sure what I did. I think it's related to android:configChanges="orientation" in the manifest.